# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '77.597639984451' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, laravel-5

I know am asking a similar question which already have lot of answers. But I am not able to figure out the Solution for my  problem.
Here I am using Laravel 5.2, I am trying to get the latlng from mysql database and display in the map. I am using Google Maps api v2.  My exact problem is that I am getting the latlng values in my console but I am not able to display it on the map. here I am attaching the full code. Any help would be greatful.

This is my MapController.php

```
class MapController extends Controller
{
public $type = 'Map';
public function getIndex()
{

   $location = DB::table('eventdata')->simplePaginate(500);
    return view('map.map')->with('location', $location);
}
```

here is my map.blade.php

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyByrgAtWpei65izUKYhdyr9-r54rrMZ8Zc&callback=initialize">
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('ico/opengts.png') }}">
    <title>Open GTS</title>

    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand active" href="#">Geo Punch Solution</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class=""><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="{{ url('aboutUs') }}">About Us</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="{{ url('accountAdmin') }}">Account Admin</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('userAdmin') }}">User Admin </a></li>

                            <li><a href="{{ url('vehicleAdmin') }}">Vehicle Admin </a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('groupAdmin') }}">Group Admin </a></li>

                            <li><a href="{{ url('geozoneAdmin') }}">Geozone Admin </a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('changePassword') }}">Change Password </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                function initialize() {

                    var map = document.getElementById('map');

                    // Initialise the map
                    var map_options = {
                        center: location,
                        zoom: 10,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    }
                    var maps = new google.maps.Map(map, map_options);

                    // Put all locations into array
                    var locations = [
                        @foreach ($location as $locations)
                        [ {{ $locations->latitude }}, {{ $locations->longitude }} ]
                        @endforeach
                        ];


                    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: location,
                            map: maps
                        });
                    }

                    // marker.setMap(map); // Probably not necessary since you set the map above

                }


                function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
                    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                            'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                            'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
                }
                {{--@endforeach--}}

            </script>

            <style type="text/css">
                #map {
                    width: 1170px;
                    height: 570px;
                    margin-top: 100px;
                    margin-left: 100px;
                }
            </style>
        </div>
    </div>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>
<p id="error"></p>
</body>
```

I am getting error like below.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '77.597639984451' of undefined

Please help me out..
Thanks in Advance

NOTE: ALL BRACES AND TAGS ARE CLOSED PROPERLY.

Comment: What does the generated JS for the `locations` array look like?

Comment: You set your map centre using this: `center: location`... where is `location` defined, and what does it look like?

Comment: Also `locations` array elements are not separated by `,`

Comment: @duncan my js for latlng values is like below                                                [ 12.995250017848, 77.601860021241 ]
 [ 13.003339979332, 77.597639984451 ]
 [ 13.003339979332, 77.597639984451 ]     At 3rd line I am getting error..

Comment: @duncan actually it's not  center:location. it's center:locations

Comment: @Matej Hey can u please tell which line you are talking about. already i included , (comma).

Comment: @Majet  Hi ,I added , (comma) in locations array.                                                                var locations = [
' foreach ($location as $locations)
  [ {{ $locations->latitude }}], [{{ $locations->longitude }} ]
 endforeach'
   ];.                                                                                                      Now am getting another error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of  js?key=AIzaSyByrgAtWpei65izUKYhdyr9-r54rrMZ8Zc&callback=initialize:94 undefined".

Comment: @RahulVp where you do `// Initialise the map
                    var map_options = {
                        center: location,`  .... where is `location` created???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matej already pointed out, you're missing a comma between your array elements.

```
var locations = [
    @foreach ($location as $locations)
    [ {{ $locations->latitude }}, {{ $locations->longitude }} ]
    @endforeach
];
```

That gives you this JS, which isn't valid:

```js
var locations = [
     [ 12.995250017848, 77.601860021241 ]
     [ 13.003339979332, 77.597639984451 ]
     [ 13.003339979332, 77.597639984451 ] 
];
```

Your code should be:

```
var locations = [
    @foreach ($location as $locations)
    [ {{ $locations->latitude }}, {{ $locations->longitude }} ],
    @endforeach
];
```

Which would then give you this JS:

```js
var locations = [
     [ 12.995250017848, 77.601860021241 ],
     [ 13.003339979332, 77.597639984451 ],
     [ 13.003339979332, 77.597639984451 ],
];
```

(the trailing comma on the last element isn't necessary, and might be marked as invalid by any JS code linting tool, but otherwise shouldn't cause any problems).

**Update:** and here's a simple way to at least provide the map itself with some kind of centre, using your existing locations.  There are better methods, such as making the map's Bounds fit all the locations, but you've not asked for that.

Firstly, create your array of locations.  Then use the first one to set the map's centre:

```
var locations = [
    @foreach ($location as $locations)
    [ {{ $locations->latitude }}, {{ $locations->longitude }} ],
    @endforeach
];

// Initialise the map
var map_options = {
    center: {lat: locations[0][0], lng: locations[0][1]},
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var maps = new google.maps.Map(map, map_options);
```

Comment: ;thanku soo much. I can see the output as u said, but am not able to see the map and marker. i pasted complete code in the question. Can you tell where did i made mistake?

Comment: @RahulVp the problem looks to me like where you specify the map's center in the Map Options: `center: location,`  Where is `location` defined?

Comment: var locations = [@foreach ($location as $locations)
 [ {{ $locations->latitude }}, {{ $locations->longitude }} ],@endforeach ];
//Initialise the map
var map_options = {center: locations,zoom: 10,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }
 var maps = new google.maps.Map(map, map_options);
 for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
 var location = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: location, map: maps, icon:'jeep.png' });} i defined center:location and wrote Map option after foreach,still am not getting

Comment: can you please tell me, where should i write Map option??

Comment: @dunacan i done.. getting all markers on the map, Can you please tell how to write polyline code in my code to draw line between the markers. I used the below code var locationPath = new google.maps.Polyline({path:new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
geodesic: true,
strokeColor: '#FFCCFF',
strokeOpacity: 2.0,
strokeWeight:2,
map:maps });
locationPath.setMap(map);    but not getting the line. Please explain this one also, in my code where should i write this, any mistake in this code?

Comment: @RahulVp you're getting onto a whole new question now. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polyline_add